# Where is the Read method of http.Request.Body defined?

Tags: go

First of all, this is a translation from Japanese, so there may be some mistakes in the wording.

The source code from the book that I am currently studying is listed below.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func body(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    len := r.ContentLength
    body := make([]byte, len)
    r.Body.Read(body)
    fmt.Fprintln(w, string(body))
}

func main() {
    server := http.Server{
        Addr: "127.0.0.1:8080",
    }
    http.HandleFunc("/body", body)
    server.ListenAndServe()
}
```

This part calls the Read method of http.Request.Body, and this question is about this part.

```golang
r.Body.Read(body)
```

In order to implement the Reader interface of io.ReadCloser, I think I need to define the Read method, but the http package documentation does not mention the Read method, so please tell me where to find the specific implementation.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader -- If you have a type and you want that type to implement the `io.Reader` interface you need to add the method `Read(p []byte) (n int, err error)` to that type.

Comment: As far as specific implementations go, there are many in the `net/http` package but all of them are unexported. For example: [`noBody`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/http/http.go#L100-L110); [`body`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/http/transfer.go#L806-L836); [`http2requestBody`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/http/h2_bundle.go#L5952-L5989)

Comment: `http.Request.Body` is just an `io.ReadCloser` interface. As such, you can assign any `io.ReadCloser` to that value, and then the `Read` method is defined wherever that type defines its `Read` method.

Comment: Your question seems to be a bit confused, though. Why do you care where `Read` is implemented? What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

you can see

```
/net/http/transfer.go
```

```
func (b *body) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    b.mu.Lock()
    defer b.mu.Unlock()
    if b.closed {
        return 0, ErrBodyReadAfterClose
    }
    return b.readLocked(p)
}
```

if noBody

```
/net/http/http.go
```

```
func (noBody) Read([]byte) (int, error)         { return 0, io.EOF }
```